# Displaying the charts from the New Relic dashboard over the API

Tags: php, api, newrelic

I'm new to the New Relic API and trying to display the charts from the application dashboard. 
In the part "Dashboard HTML fragment (One application)" is only returns a table with the row of the application I want (basically the same as in "Dashboard HTML fragment (All applications)"). I thought it's going to return me the detailed charts and information. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover over a chart in the New Relic Dashboard, a "+" will appear in the lower right corner of that chart. You can click that "+" and then choose "embed" to create an html embeddable link. As long as your timeframe is set to "ending now" when you create the chart, the chart will actively update on any page that you embed it into.

Answer (score 0):

You can also now explore everything the data API can give you with our API explorer at api.newrelic.com. After you feed it your API key, it lets you click through possible calls and shows shows you the response right there in the web UI, and writes a handy curl to make the calls yourself!